# Wildcard string replace in C#

Tags: c#

I have a large file that references a URL within it. It always has the format:

```
 URL="........." - where the ellipses are the URL.
```

I have a new URL would like to replace the previous with and I was wondering if there was any sort of wildcard string replace.

```
Example:
A large string contains: URL="google.com"

Problem: 
I need to replace the above with: URL="123.com"
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string largeString = ".....URL=\"google.com\" ....";
string pattern = "URL=\"([^ \"]*)\"";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(largeString, "URL=\"123.com\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Replace(line, @"URL\s*=\s*"".+?""", @"URL=""123.com""");
```